# p:dialog doesn't work when I call jquery code

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

PrimeFaces `<p:dialog>` doesn't work when I call jquery code (jquery.js, plugin.js), but when I don't call the jquery code it works, and I need the both. I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.jq.draggable is not a function

My page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>

    <!-- ============================================
        Stylesheets
    ============================================= -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/tipsy.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/bootstrap.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/font-awesome.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/prettyPhoto.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/rs/css/rs-settings.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/responsive.css"
        type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <!-- ============================================
        External JavaScripts
    ============================================= -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../template/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../template/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <!-- ============================================
        Document Title
    ============================================= -->
    <title>BJ</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="container clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="../template/images/logo.png"
                        alt="CoWorker" title="CoWorker" /></a>
                </div>
                <div id="primary-menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="current"><a href="index.php"><div>Home</div> <span>Let's
                                    Start here</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><div>Sliders</div></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="index-layer.php"><div>Layer Slider</div></a></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="content-wrap">
                <div class="container clearfix">

                    <h:form>



                        <p:commandButton value="ADD" action="#{patientBean.create}">
                        </p:commandButton>

                        <p:outputPanel>

                            <p:dataTable var="patient" value="#{patientBean.listPatient}"
                                widgetVar="carsTable"
                                emptyMessage="No datas found with given criteria"
                                filteredValue="#{patientBean.filtredListPatient}" reflow="true"
                                rows="1" paginator="true" rendered="true">

                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <p:outputPanel>
                                        <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
                                        <p:inputText id="globalFilter"
                                            onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()" style="width:150px"
                                            placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                </f:facet>

                                <p:column filterBy="#{patient.cin}" headerText="cin"
                                    filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{patient.cin}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{patient.cin}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column filterBy="#{patient.nom}" headerText="nom"
                                    filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{patient.nom}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{patient.nom}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column filterBy="#{patient.prenom}" headerText="prenom"
                                    filterMatchMode="contains" sortBy="#{patient.prenom}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{patient.prenom}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Actions">
                                    <p:outputPanel>

                                        <p:commandButton value="EDIT" action="#{patientBean.getRow()}"
                                            oncomplete="PF('popEditPatient').show();">
                                        </p:commandButton>

                                        <p:commandButton action="#{patientBean.delete}" value="DELETE">
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </p:outputPanel>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </h:form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="copyrights" class="copyrights-dark">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="col_half">Created by JALLOULI Bilel</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="gotoTop" class="icon-angle-up"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../template/js/custom.js"></script>

    <p:dialog widgetVar="popEditPatient" modal="true" header="EDIT">
        <p:outputPanel autoUpdate="true">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:outputLabel value="cin :" />
                    <p:inputText id="cin" value="#{patientBean.patient.cin}"
                        disabled="true" />


                    <h:outputLabel value="nom :" />
                    <p:inputText id="nom" value="#{patientBean.patient.nom}" />

                    <h:outputLabel value="prenom :" />
                    <p:inputText id="prenom" value="#{patientBean.patient.prenom}" />

                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#{patientBean.save}"
                    oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed) PF('popEditPatient').hide();" />
                <p:commandButton value="Annuler" action="#{patientBean.init}"
                    oncomplete="PF('popEditPatient').hide();" />
            </h:form>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

faceconfig :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
 version="2.2">
  <converter>
  <converter-id>entitySelectItemsConverter</converter-id>
  <converter-class>tn.com.bj.presentation.tools.EntitySelectItemsConverter</converter-class>
 </converter>
<!--  
 <navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/views/listPatient.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>listePatient</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/views/listPatient.xhtml</to-view-id>
   <redirect/>
  </navigation-case>
 </navigation-rule>
-->

 <!-- JSF and Spring are integrated -->
 <application>
  <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
 </application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Don't manually include jquery.js. or a full plugins.js.

Comment: but i need them to my personal menu

Comment: Pf has a jquery, can't you use that? And you can (should) strip the plugins.js to those that are not already in PF. You can do this on the jquery site and for the jquery version that is in pf